# Confused over global.asax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

I have a class called `Global` that derives from `HttpApplication`.

Oddly, I see a lot of methods inside `Global` that look like:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

The code is definitely executing inside this method, so the method is being called from somewhere, but where? The methods aren't marked overload?

Secondly, I derived a class from `Global`, let's call it `GlobalFoo`.

Again, if I create a method called `Application_Start()` it will get called inside my derived class, otherwise nothing that's in `Global` will get called so I might as well be deriving from an empty class.

Can anyone offer any advice? Am I missing some fundamental part of ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so the method is being called from somewhere, but where?

**This functions are called from the Application Pool** (from each pool that you have assign),   to signal start-up/end events of your application and help your with initializations.

Every pool that is assign to run your web application runs those functions.

asp.net is **helping you create different objects/code** external or not that can run together, and that's **why you see that all of your registered code run**. Its a help to create more than one "start up" routines that do different thinks.

This [is an example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/WebPageSecurity_v2.aspx), this module just check the secure protocol by him self... and you do not need to change anything on your code, just register it.

Answer (score 0):

IIS calls the different Global.asax events through the asp.net isapi filter.

Perhaps [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx) will help explain.

Answer (score -1):

The Global.asax file is an optional file used to declare and handle application and session-level events and objects for an ASP.NET web site running on an IIS Web Server

some of the key events in this file are:

- Application_Init: Fires when the application initializes for the first time.
- Application_Start: Fires the first time an application starts.
- Session_Start: Fires the first time when a user’s session is started.
- Application_BeginRequest: Fires each time a new request comes in.
- Application_EndRequest: Fires when the application terminates.
- Application_AuthenticateRequest: Indicates that a request is ready to be authenticated.
- Application_Error: Fires when an unhandled error occurs within the application.
- Session_End: Fires whenever a single user Session ends or times out.
- Application_End: Fires when the application ends or times out (Typically used for application cleanup logic).

For a complete list of Global.asax events see "[Global.asax Events](http://blog.ie-soft.de/post/2007/12/globalasax-events.aspx)".

Comment: I don't really care about the events themselves, Im confused over where / how they're being called